# Filter out rows based on multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can identify the rows I want to remove from a dataframe using the following code:

```
df[(df.Year.isin(range(200,205))) & (df.id== 'string')]
```

How do I remove these rows from the dataframe?

I tried the following solution but it didn't work:

```
df.drop[(df.Year.isin(range(200,205))) & (df.id== 'string'), axis = 0]
```

Comment: `df = df[~((df.Year.isin(range(200,205))) & (df.id== 'string'))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the rows by index as well

```
df.drop(df[(df.Year.isin(range(200,205))) & (df.id== 'string')].index, inplace=True)
```

Another way suggested by @JoshFriedlander

```
df = df[~((df.Year.isin(range(200,205))) & (df.id== 'string'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

my go to solution would be:

`df = df[(df['year'] >= 200) & (df['year'] <= 205) & (df['id'] == 'string')]`